# Is there an abstract definition of a matrix being "upper triangular"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis, triangularization

Another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4101200/a-3-times3-triangular-matrix-has-a-repeated-eigenvalue-if-it-is-the-square-of#4101200) brought this up.  The only definition I have ever seen for a matrix being upper triangular is, written in component forms, "all the components below the main diagonal are zero."  But of course that property is basis dependent.  It is not preserved under change of basis.

Yet it doesn't seem as if it would be purely arbitrary because the product of upper triangular matrices is upper triangular, and so forth.  It has closure.  Is there some other sort of transformation besides a basis transformation that might be relevant here?  It seems as if a set of matrices having this property should have some sort of invariants.

Is there some sort of isomorphism between the sets of upper triangular matrices in different bases?

Comment: The abstract concept is a *fan*. See the first page of Chapter X of Lang's Linear Algebra, available at https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-1949-9_10.pdf

Comment: I do think it depends on an ordered basis. Even reordering the basis of an upper triangular matrix can make a matrix change from upper-triangular to not. So it isn’t a property of linear transformations.

Comment: You can take any partial order on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and get an algebra of matrices where $a_{ij}$ is zero unless $i\leq j$ in the partial order. Much is known about such functions. For example, there is a generalization of “Möbius functions.” (See “Incidence Algebra.”) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra

Comment: Thank you for the link to Lang's book and the relevant page.  I am reluctant to buy yet *another* linear algebra textbook; I must own a dozen at this point and most of them are redundant.  But the idea makes sense.

Comment: The fact that it satisfies closure properties does not exclude a strong basis dependence. It is like in group theory the properties of being a subgroup and being invariant under conjugation, which are rather orthogonal to one another (though they can go together, as in normal subgroups) In fact the closure properties of upper triangular matrices is due to the set being the stabiliser of a (complete) flag.

Comment: There is the motion of "triangulizable matrices"  which may be what you have in mind?

Comment: If you cascade linear systems (say, forced linear ODEs), if you stack the states consistently — either from input to output or vice versa — the dynamics of the whole cascade is described by a block triangular matrix. If each system is $1$-dimensional, then the matrix is triangular. Does this interest you in any way?

Comment: @IHF  thanks again for the link to Lang's book.  I remember him from San Jose State back in the last century.   Alas, I never had a course from him.  I should have.  So many of the great ones are gone now.

Comment: Over a finite field, $\mathbb F_{p^n},$the upper triangular matrices with $1$ on the diagonal are a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Many true things can be said about upper-triangular matrices, obviously... :)

In my own experience, a useful more-functional (rather than notational) thing that can be said is that the subgroup of $GL_n$ consisting of upper-triangular matrices is the *stabilizer* of the *flag* (nested sequence) of subspaces consisting of the span of $e_1$, the span of $e_1$ and $e_2$, ... with standard basis vectors.

Concretely, this means the following. The matrix multiplication of a triangular matrix $A$ and $e_1$, $Ae_1$, is equal to a multiple of $e_1$, right? However, $Ae_2$ is more than a multiple of $e_2$: it can be any linear combination of $e_1$ and $e_2$. Generally, if you set $V_i= \operatorname{span}(e_1, \ldots, e_i) $, try to show that $A$ is upper triangular if and only if $A(V_i) \subseteq V_i$. The nested sequence of spaces

$$ 0 = V_0 \subset V_1 \subset \ldots \subset V_n = \mathbb{R}^n$$

is called a *flag* of the total space.

One proves a lemma that *any* maximal chain of subspaces can be mapped to that "standard" chain by an element of $GL_n$. In other words, no matter which basis you are using: being triangular is intrinsically to respect a flag with $\dim(V_i) = i$ (the last condition translate the *maximality* of the flag).

As Daniel Schepler aptly commented, while an ordered basis gives a maximal flag, a maximal flag does *not* quite specify a basis. There are more things that can be said about flags versus bases... unsurprisingly... :)

Comment: +1, I think this is the "right answer". Maybe simplifying a bit the language can make it better suited for the OP (just an impression on the background he has)

Comment: @AndreaMarino, I'd be happy if you would care to edit to a more helpful language. I am perhaps unable to imagine it...

Comment: @AndreaMarino you are right that it's a stretch for my background, but now I know what to look up.

Comment: Thank you, @paulgarrett!

Comment: @RobertTheTutor, :) .... :)

Comment: I added some further explanations on the language. @paulgarrett: please check you agree with this version!

Comment: The upper triangular matrices make sense when even in infinite dimensions, even with row/column indices infinite in both directions. Then the “flag” is a sequence of subspaces $\cdots\subset V_{-2}\subset V_{-1}\subset V_0\subset V_1\subset V_2\subset\cdots$ where all the $V_i$ are infinite dimensional.

Comment: @AndreaMarino, seems fine. Thanks! :)

Comment: "In my own experience, a useful coordinate-independent ... with standard basis vectors." This seems inconsistent.

Comment: @Acccumulation, I meant to indicate that thinking about the original "upper triangular" in a slightly different way first makes clearer how it depends on coordinates... but, then, transition to slightly _less_ coordinate-dependent, in the sense of reference to "flag of subspaces".

Comment: It might be worthwhile to note that from the maximal flag, you can't extract a unique ordered basis.  For example, $\lambda e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n$ (with $\lambda \ne 0$) gives the same flag, and so does $e_1, e_1 + e_2, e_3, \ldots, e_n$.  So, the information about the maximal flag is somewhere strictly between the vector space structure and the ordered basis (probably notionally much closer to the ordered basis, but still).

Comment: @DanielSchepler, indeed. I'll edit to reflect this. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Being upper triangular is not a property of linear transformations unless you have an ordered basis. Even changing the order of a basis can change an upper triangular matrix to a matrix which is not, or vice versa.

The upper triangular $n\times n$ matrices are the second most simple form of an [incidence algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra), where we take the partially ordered set to be $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ with the usual order.

The most trivial incidence algebra is the algebra of diagonal matrices, where the order is $i\preccurlyeq  j$ iff $i=j.$

One interesting thing about upper-triangular matrices is that they form an algebra even when infinite-dimensional. This is because, while multiplication requires infinite sums, all but finitely many of them are zero. You can even take upper triangular matrices with rows/columns infinite in both directions by using $(\mathbb Z,\leq)$ for your Poset.

(In a general infinite poset $P$ what is required for the algebra’s multiplication to be well-defined is for the poset to be “locally finite.”)

Answer (score 10):

Here are two points regarding your question.

First, as you suggest, for any two bases the upper triangular matrices with respect to those bases are indeed related: the change of basis matrix $B$ conjugates every upper triangular matrix $M$ in one basis to an upper triangular matrix $BMB^{-1}$ in the other basis.

Second, there are indeed some useful invariants associated to upper triangular matrices, namely group theoretic invariants. This is clearest in the group $GL(n,\mathbb C)$ of all invertible $n \times n$ complex matrices. First (and this is easy) the full subgroup of upper triangular matrices is a solvable group. What's more (and this is [Lie-Kolchin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie%E2%80%93Kolchin_theorem)) for every solvable subgroup $H < GL(n,\mathbb C)$ there is a basis of $\mathbb C^n$ with respect to which $H$ is upper triangular; equivalently, there exists a matrix $B \in GL(n,\mathbb C)$ such that the subgroup $BHB^{-1}$ is upper triangular.

Answer (score 8):

If we consider a certain class of upper triangular matrices,  namely,  the ones that are *strictly upper triangular*, then there's indeed a nice characterization in terms of *nilpotency*.  A matrix is nilpotent if there's a nonnegative integer $k $ for which  $N^k=0$.
In particular,  a matrix is nilpotent if and only if it's similar to a strictly upper triangular matrix with blocks $S_1,\dots,S_n $ above the diagonal.   In other words,  of the form  $\begin{pmatrix}0&S_1&0&\dots&0\\0&0&S_2&\dots&0\\\vdots\\0&\dots&0&0&S_n\\0&0&\dots&0&0\end {pmatrix} $.

Answer (score 5):

One can give as well a recursive definition in the form of a "block decomposition"

$$\begin{cases}T_{n+1}=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}a&V^T\\ \hline 0&T_{n}\end{array}\right] \ \text{with} \ a \in \mathbb{R}, \ 0, V \in \mathbb{R^n} \\ T_1=a \in \mathbb{R}\end{cases}$$

where notation $T_n$ is for a upper triangular matrix of order $n$, and $0$ for a zero vector.

Answer (score 3):

An upper triangular matrix in a sense "in between" an arbitrary matrix and a diagonal one. With a diagonal matrix, each elementary vector generates a one-dimensional subspaces, and each of these subspaces is closed under the linear transformation. With a UT matrix, each elementary vector gets sent to a linear combination of elementary vectors of equal or lower index. So each initial subset of the set of elementary vectors generate a closed subspace. And then in between upper triangular matrices and diagonal matrices is Jordan canonical form, which is a block matrix where each block has only one unique eigenvalue.

$\text{arbitrary matrices} \supset \text{upper triangular matrices} \supset \text{Jordan canonical form}\supset \text{diagonal matrices}$

All linear transformations have a basis for which it is in Jordan canonical form (at least, if we allow complex numbers), so all matrices are similar to an upper diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I mean you can say it in a more formal way e.g. if $M\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ has elements $a_{ij}$ where $i,j=[1,2..N]$ then:
$$a_{ij}=0\,\,\forall i>j $$
and can take any value for $i\le j$

Is this what you were looking for?